# How To Handle UIImage on device rotation

Tags: iphone

I have a UIScrollView with a UIImage inside. The following code initializes the image properly (it's width is the same as the width of the scrollView):

```
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    ...

    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"map1.jpg"]];
    imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    imageView.autoresizingMask = ( UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth );
    [imageScrollView addSubview:imageView];

    imageScrollView.contentSize = [imageView frame].size;

    ...

    // calculate minimum scale to perfectly fit image width, and begin at that scale
    float minimumScale = [imageScrollView frame].size.width  / [imageView frame].size.width;
    //imageScrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1.0;
    imageScrollView.minimumZoomScale = minimumScale;
    imageScrollView.zoomScale = minimumScale;
}
```

What I want to do is to set the size to perfectly fit (like above) when the device rotates. Here's what I've tried to do:

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {
  float newScale = [imageScrollView frame].size.width  / [imageView frame].size.width;
  imageScrollView.zoomScale = newScale;
}
```

For some reasons this doesn't work at all. The only way that I was able to make it work was to initialize another UIImage and do all the initialization process again, which doesn't feel right to me.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should also change .contentSize of scroll view.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work unfortunately. I think the problem is with the UIImageView, not the UIScrollView.

Comment: Ok, please describe what do you see on screen after rotation, i.e. what is the size of UIImage and so on?

Comment: The image is zoomed in (way more than necesary)

Comment: That's because of UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth - image is resized proprtionally screen width change (after rotation). Check image frame, and change it to the value it has at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks for you help Nickolay. Unfortunately I wasn't able to follow your advice. How should I change the image frame?

Comment: You should set imageView.frame to one it has after load.
Or try to disable autoresizing.

Comment: Ok I did that. The only problem is that the image would have the same size as it was in portrait mode.